# IP banning via .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ip, bandwidth

Liteserver on a Shared access host here.

I'm trying to get rid of a lot of bots who waste my resources for nothing.

I can successfully restrict access to some of them using a specific User Agent, but I can't ban their IP addresses, together with those of a lot of chinese ones who are constantly scanning my website. I am still seeing AhrefsBot IP (5.10.83.44) in the access log, even if its IP is banned (see the last line of the htaccess file). The rules should already be inherited by /gallery subfolder.

> 5.10.83.44 - - [07/Sep/2013:00:56:42 +0200] "GET /gallery/addfav.php?pid=858&referer=displayimage.php%3Fpid%3D858
>   HTTP/1.1" 302 156 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0;
>   +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"

Root's .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
    Cache-Control: Private
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

#inherit from root htaccess and append at last, necessary in root too
RewriteOptions inherit

#block bad bots
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^spider$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^robot$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^crawl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)AhrefsBot(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^discovery$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} 360Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Ezooms/1.0 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MJ12bot/v1.4.4
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://go.away/

#include caching for images
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 360 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 week"  
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType font/truetype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/opentype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^id.foo.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.id.foo.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/foo\.myopenid\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#ban bots and stuff
order allow,deny
deny from 113.212.68.114
deny from 77.232.159.95
deny from 1.12.0.0/14
deny from 1.24.0.0/13
deny from 1.32.0.0/16
[...]
deny from 5.10.83.0/23
allow from all
```

/gallery subfolder .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#inherit from root htaccess and append at last
RewriteOptions inherit

##/**************************************************
##  Coppermine 1.5.x Plugin - sef_urls
##  *************************************************
##  Copyright (c) 2003-2007 Coppermine Dev Team
##  *************************************************
##  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
##  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
##  the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
##  (at your option) any later version.
##  ********************************************
##  $HeadURL$
##  $Revision$
##  $LastChangedBy$
##  $Date$
##  **************************************************/

#Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

# RewriteEngine on

#  Uncomment the following line if your webserver's
#  URL is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update "YOUR_COPPERMINE_ROOT" (just / for root)

#RewriteBase /gallery

#
# Language translation
#

RewriteRule cerca.html(.*) search.php$1 [NC]

RewriteRule contatti.html(.*) contact.php$1 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)migliore(.*) $1toprated$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)popolari(.*) $1topn$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)osservazionedi(.*) $1lastcomby$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)osservazione(.*) $1lastcom$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)pagina(.*) $1page$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)listautenti(.*) $1usermgr$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)profilo(.*) $1profile$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)miniature(.*) $1thumbnails$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)mostra(.*) $1displayimage$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)novitadi(.*) $1lastupby$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)novita(.*) $1lastup$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)cerca(.*) $1search$2 [NC]

RewriteRule (.*)top(.*) $1top_display_media$2 [NC]


#
# Rewrite usrmgr urls
#

RewriteRule usermgr-page-([0-9]*).html(.*) usermgr.php?page=$1$2 [NC]

RewriteRule usermgr.html(.*) usermgr.php$1 [NC]

#
# Rewrite index urls
#

RewriteRule index.html(.*) index.php$1 [NC]

RewriteRule index-([0-9]*)\.html(.*) index.php?cat=$1$2 [NC]

RewriteRule index-([0-9]*)-page-([0-9]*)\.html(.*) index.php?cat=$1&page=$2$3 [NC]


#
# Rewrite thumbnail urls
#

RewriteRule thumbnails-lastupby-([0-9]+)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=lastupby&uid=$1$2 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-lastcomby-([0-9]+)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=lastcomby&uid=$1$2 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-lastupby-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=lastupby&cat=$1&uid=$2&page=$3$4 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-lastcomby-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=lastcomby&cat=$1&uid=$2&page=$3$4 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-([a-z0-9]*)-([\-]?[0-9]*)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=$1&cat=$2$3 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-page-([0-9]*)-([a-z0-9]*).*\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=$2&page=$1$3 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-([a-z0-9]*)-([\-]?[0-9]*)-page-([0-9]*)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=$1&cat=$2&page=$3$4 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-search-keyword-(.*)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=search&keywords=on&search=$1$2 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-search-(.*)\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=search&search=$1$2 [NC]

RewriteRule thumbnails-([0-9a-z]*).*\.html(.*) thumbnails.php?album=$1$2 [NC]


#
# Rewrite displayimage urls
#

RewriteRule displayimage-lastcom-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-page-([\-]?[0-9]+).html(.*) displayimage.php?album=lastcom&cat=$1&pid=$2&msg_id=$3&page=$4$5 [NC]

RewriteRule displayimage-([a-z0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)\.html(.*) displayimage.php?album=$1&cat=$2&pid=$3&uid=$4&msg_id=$5&page=$6$7 [NC]

RewriteRule displayimage-([a-z0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)\.html(.*) displayimage.php?album=$1&cat=$2&pid=$3&uid=$4$5 [NC]

RewriteRule displayimage-([a-z0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+).*\.html(.*) displayimage.php?album=$1&cat=$2&pid=$3$4 [NC]

RewriteRule displayimage-([a-z0-9]+)-([\-]?[0-9]+).*\.html(.*) displayimage.php?album=$1&pid=$2$3 [NC]

RewriteRule displayimage-([0-9]+).*\.html(.*) displayimage.php?pid=$1$2 [NC]


#
# Rewrite users profiles
#

RewriteRule profile-op-([a-z0-9_]+)\.html(.*) profile.php?op=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule profile-([0-9]+).*\.html(.*) profile.php?uid=$1$2 [NC]
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, but unfortunately I have no clue.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

According to that [AhrefBot's link](https://ahrefs.com/robot/index.php), this is all you need to do to stop that particular bot:

```
user-agent: AhrefsBot
disallow: /
```

By adding the above to a `robots.txt` file in your document root.

The other thing is this:

```
order allow,deny
```

Is in the wrong order. According to [apache's mod_access documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order):

> **Allow,Deny**
>
> First, all *Allow* directives are evaluated; at least one must match, or the request is rejected. Next, all *Deny* directives are evaluated. If any matches, the request is rejected. Last, any requests which do not match an *Allow* or a *Deny* directive are denied by default.

Because you have "Allow from all", it gets evaluated first and the different "Deny"'s never get evaluated. So you want:

```
Order Deny,Allow
```

Comment: It was the first thing I tried, days ago. Unfortunately, they don't respect robots.txt at all.
Thanks for pointing out what was wrong in my .htaccess. I'll let you know if it will finally start working.

Comment: Still not working. `5.10.83.44 - - [07/Sep/2013:10:31:32 +0200] "GET /gallery/displayimage.php?album=14&pid=513 HTTP/1.1" 302 156 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"`

Comment: @flapane Well, the log entry you posted says that the response was a "302", which looks like is caused by this rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://go.away/`, though the rewrite engine *should* honor only the rules in the gallery htaccess file. I guess try moving the mod_access stuff to the top of the htaccess file?

Comment: Exactly, the http 302 answer means that root .htaccess file is honored by the /gallery/.htaccess file.
I moved all the mod_access restrictions to the very top of the file, but it's still not working.
`5.10.83.84 - - [07/Sep/2013:10:46:24 +0200] "GET /gallery/addfav.php?pid=1239&referer=displayimage.php%3Fpid%3D1239 HTTP/1.1" 302 156 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"`

Comment: @flapane You have `RewriteOptions inherit` in your gallery htaccess, so the parent rules are appended to the end. But still don't know why mod_access is being ignored. Is the document root setup to allow the override "Limit"? As in: `AllowOverride Limit`, which is was mod_access needs in order to use allow/deny

Comment: I tried this on a testing subfolder, and I got a 403 Forbidden, so I guess AllowOverride Limit is enabled:
`#AuthConfig

AuthName "Secret"

#FileInfo

ErrorDocument 404 index.php

#Indexes

DefaultIcon /icon/unknown.xbm 

#Limit

Deny From All

#Options

Options FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Here's the culprit: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.*)AhrefsBot(.*)` had a higer priority than `deny from 5.10.83.0/23`, no matter if mod_access stuff comes before the `#block bad bots` section.